# Python pexpect not working as expected

Tags: python, shell, pexpect

Im trying to write a program that runs some shell commands wit emulated user data.

The problem is that the shell command does not run correctly without this line in the end of the code:

```
raw_input('press <enter> to exit')
```

How can i get rid of that line?

```
child = pexpect.spawn('grunt init:gruntfile')
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout

child.expect ('Is the DOM involved in ANY way?')
child.sendline ('y')
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout

child.expect ('Will files be concatenated or minified?')
child.sendline ('y')
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout

child.expect ('Will you have a package.json file?')
child.sendline ('y')
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout

child.expect ('Do you need to make any changes to the above before continuing?')
child.sendline ('n')
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout

raw_input('press <enter> to exit')
```

Comment: Is that title meant to be a joke ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem appears to be that without the raw_input to slow the program down, your python script is exiting before the child process is finished (and killing the child process in the process).

I think `pexpect.wait()` is supposed to handle this situation, but it sounds from [the documentation](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) like wait() will hang if there is unread output after the child process exits, and without knowing the details of your child process I can't say whether or not there is a risk that will happen.  Some combination of read() and wait() might work, or if it's too much trouble to figure that out you could just time.sleep() a number of seconds.

Comment: The wait() did it. Thanks alot!

Comment: From the documentation, it sounds like `read()` should be used. Given no arguments, it will read until it gets an EOF. Unlike `read_nonblocking()`, it should be blocking, and so wait for the process to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I know that it has been a while since this question was asked, but I came across it and thought I would volunteer what worked for me.

I basically just setup a while loop that asked if the process was complete and then would throw an error if it never completed. That way I would have a more flexible wait that would error out in a way that was more meaningful to me while not gumming up my automation too bad.

I should also point out that this was for waiting for something to execute at the end of a series of interactive prompts before the program exited. So, if you are waiting for something that is in the middle of a process, then this wouldn't work so well. However, you probably could modify it to handle different situations.

```
import time, sys, pexpect


some_function():
    child = pexpect.spawn('some command here')

    if debugging:  # Just in case you also want to see the output for debugging
        child.logfile = sys.stdout

    # Do stuff
    child expect('some regex')
    child sendline('some response')

    sleep_count = 0  # For tracking how long it slept for.
    acceptable_duration = 120  # The amount of time that I'm willing to wait

    # Note that apparently solaris can take a while to reply to isalive(),
    # so the process may go a lot longer than what you set the duration to.

    while child.isalive():
        if sleep_count > acceptable_duration
            sys.stderr.write("Useful text explaining that the process never exited."
            sys.exit(1)
        time.sleep(1)
```